# Forecasting excess mortality with ARIMA model

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, data-transformation, prediction-interval

I am using the forecast package by Prof Hyndman, and have had success fitting ARIMA models to excess mortality (from the COVID-19 pandemic) data. I am currently trying to produce plots for cumulative excess deaths, but am unsure how to proceed about producing prediction intervals for these plots.

In more detail, I am fitting an ARIMA model using monthly mortalaity (rate) data from January 2000 to Feburary 2020 via the `auto.arima()` function. I then use `forecast()` to work out the counterfactual deaths for March 2020- March 2021 (deaths that would have occurred in the absence of the pandemic). This also gives me prediction intervals for the counterfactual deaths.
However, I want to produce a plot for **cumulative excess death rates** starting from March 2020. If this were a normal linear model, then to work out the confidence intervals I would simply use the following:

```r
data$cumse[1]<-sqrt(data$se[1]^2)
for(i in 2:nrow(data)){
  data$cumse[i]<-sqrt(data$cumse[i-1]^2 + data$se[i]^2)
}
```

where `data$se` is the standard error for my counterfactual deaths for March 2020-March 2021, and `data$cumse` would be the standard error for the cumulative excess deaths. To then produce the prediction intervals, I would simply take the bounds to be `data$cumexcess`$\pm$`1.96*data$cumse`.

However, my ARIMA model contains AR terms so I don't think the above would be appropriate as it assumes independence. Please could someone help me work out how to produce prediction intervals in this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

If `auto.arima` handles excess rates $\Delta x_t$ and produces interval forecasts, it will trivially handle cumulative excess rates $x_t$ (by first-differencing them), too. Supply the cumulatively summed series $x_t$ to `auto.arima`, and you will get the forecast interval for it.